# Is it generally considered to be bad practice to use firstChild etc in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I once read that accessing the dom directly is considered *bad practice* when using react JS and wanted to clarify a use case in an accordion component I built. The component needs to animate when it expands/collapses so I decided to use CSS transitions for this.

To achieve this I essentially stick the element with the  content of the accordion tab into an array which which is stored in a `useRef` object. Then, when the user clicks the trigger, I access the ref and alter the style property of the element, and other related element, by using methods such as `firstElementChild` and `closest`.

The resulting component is pretty clean and the method works well, I was just concerned whether or not there is something I am missing. I have seen multiple articles online which either use a library or nested hooks which ultimately use `setTimeout` to apply a style. This feels hacky to me.

Anyway, some code...

**Event handlers:**

```
const tabsRef = useRef<TabRef[]>([]);
  const indRef = useRef<number[]>([]);

  const alterTabs = (newIndexes: number[]) => {
    tabsRef.current.forEach((tab) => {
      tab.element.style.setProperty(
        "height",
        newIndexes.includes(tab.index)
          ? `${tab?.element?.firstElementChild?.clientHeight}px`
          : "0px"
      );
      tab.element
        ?.closest("[aria-expanded]")
        ?.setAttribute("aria-expanded", `${newIndexes.includes(tab.index)}`);
    });
  };

  const selectDay: React.MouseEventHandler = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>
  ) => {
    const trigger = event.currentTarget;
    trigger?.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    const triggeredIndex = Number(trigger.dataset.index);
    const newIndexes = indRef.current.includes(triggeredIndex)
      ? [...indRef.current.filter((index) => index !== triggeredIndex)]
      : [...indRef.current, triggeredIndex];
    alterTabs(newIndexes);
    indRef.current = newIndexes;
    trigger?.removeAttribute("disabled");
  };
```

**Relevant Render method:**

```
          {items.map((item, i) => (
            <AccordionTriggerWrapper
              key={Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 9)}
              data-index={i}
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              <AccordionTrigger>
                <Button margin="sm" data-index={i} onClick={selectDay}>
                  <AccordionTitleIcon>
                    {item.icon && getIcon(item.icon)}
                    {item.title}
                  </AccordionTitleIcon>
                  {[getIcon("minus", 10), getIcon("plus", 10)]}
                </Button>
              </AccordionTrigger>
              <Content>
                <ContentInner
                  ref={(element) => {
                    tabsRef.current[i] = {
                      index: i,
                      element: element?.parentElement as HTMLElement,
                    };
                  }}
                >
                  <ReactMarkdown
                    key={Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 9)}
                  >
                    {item.content}
                  </ReactMarkdown>
                </ContentInner>
              </Content>
            </AccordionTriggerWrapper>
          ))}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's bad practice to dominate the DOM by yourself but small things like you do above, you can do it. Anyway, I can recommend you some react styling components like react-transition-group(especially), and you can take a look at React-Motion and React-Move. hit me **up** if it's helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).